# How can a SonarPlugin query its settings?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I'm currently developing a SonarQube plugin and want to ask whether there is a way to query the settings from the sonar-project-properties file at run time.

More specifically, in the sonar-project-properties file you can set the analysis mode to analysis, preview or incremental, e.g., sonar.analysis.mode=analysis.

Due to the problem that preview and incremental mode run into an error, I want to disable the plugin when one of these two modes is specified.

I know that there is the sonar.preview.excludePlugins setting for excluding plugins, however, I cannot use it. In other words, I have to figure out at run-time which mode is set.

Can someone give me a hint, because I haven't found an approach for querying the settings from a sonar-project.properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins can not auto-disable themselves through the standard plugin exclusion properties. 
The solution is that your plugin extensions, for instance sensors, read the properties through the component `org.sonar.api.config.Settings` and then accordingly continue or stop execution. Basically:

```
public class MySensor implements Sensor {
  private final Settings settings;

  public MySensor(Settings settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  public void analyse(Project module, SensorContext context) {
    if ("analysis ".equals(settings.getString("sonar.analysis.mode"))) {
      return;
    }
    // else continue...
  }
}
```

Comment: Even thought I'm using a Decorator, the solution is the same. Thanks!